# Running Tasks in VSCode with Different User Permissions

Tags: java, scala, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to configure VSCode to run tasks as a different user?

I am able to sudo as a different user and execute /"opt"/"java8"/"bin"/"java"  -classpath "some/path/.tmp/some_app.jar test. Can I achieve the same using run | debug directly:

[image]

Tried manipulating launch.json with no success.

Comment: please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Any updates here?